# How to add excel file as an attachment in an email action Using Microsoft Flow?

Tags: sql-server, excel, outlook

I'm executing an SQL query. The output of a SQL query needs to be added to excel file. Now, that that excel file with SQL resultant data needs to be attached as an attachment while sending an email using "Send an email" action in Microsoft flow. How can I do that?

Comment: What code are you using to add the result to the file?

Comment: There's no where near enough information provided to answer this question properly.  How are you executing the SQL?  How are you capturing the result of the SQL?